Power BI Report Recreation / Modification assistance
I have experience working with Power BI, however I find myself struggling with designing visually appealing and well-organized reports. I now realize that creating effective visuals requires a creative touch, and I often face challenges in arranging visuals on a page in a way that looks clean and professional.
I have attached a .PBIX file that I’ve spent considerable time putting together. While I would like to incorporate additional elements such as KPIs and a banner, I’m finding it difficult to create sufficient space for them without compromising the overall layout. When I look at other Power BI examples online, I notice they often include a greater number of visuals—such as headings, KPIs, and other elements—yet still maintain a polished and cohesive appearance.
I would greatly appreciate it if someone could review my Power BI report and provide suggestions on how I might improve the layout and design to achieve a more professional and visually appealing result.
The link to the pbix is here
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_oWAaVmJ5Ev9oxmn0S1WYfP6JXLLilOJ/view?usp=sharing
